# SQL timeout exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Why do I get this exception in my code? I restarted the server, changed ports, etc, but nothing is working.

What's wrong?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;user=armin;password=root;");
con.Open();

SqlCommand result = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT userid FROM KDDData.dbo.userprofile order by userid", con);

SqlDataReader reader = result.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(reader);

List<string> userids = new List<string>(dt.Rows.Count);

foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    userids.Add(item.ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim());
}

con.Close();

con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;user=armin;password=root;");
con.Open();

foreach (string user in userids)
{
    DataTable temp = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand result1 = new SqlCommand(
    "select itemid from KDDTrain.dbo.train where userid=" + user, con);

    SqlDataReader reader1 = result1.ExecuteReader();

    if (!reader1.HasRows)
    {
        continue;
    }

    temp.Load(reader1);
}
```

The first query works fine, but the second doesn't. As you can see I even use some other `SqlConnection` but it still doesn't work.

Note:The database i'm working with has atleast 100 milion records,thought may be this would be a problem.

Comment: i guess you want itemids per userid ... so why you are trying to fill it in same name as 'temp' ?

Comment: Where do you get the exception? In the opening of the second connection?

Comment: By the way, the data filled in the temp datatable created inside the loop will be wiped out at the first continue.

Comment: @Steve in the query part(reader),not the opening.

Comment: Dispose your reader after foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows){ userids.Add(item.ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim()); } and also close the con after temp.Load(reader1)} and also the reader1 ... Instead of all this... the clean way is to use USING for initializng the readers and connection :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir the code you are seeing is not complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something doesn't look right in your connection string
I always seen `"server=localhost; user=armin;password=root"` in connections strings for MySql not for SqlServer where instead I will use `"Data Source=(LOCAL);Integrated Security=SSPI"` or the INSTANCE name of SqlServer. Are you sure that the first query works?.

However I think you should use the appropriate using statement

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;user=armin;password=root;"))
{
    using(SqlCommand result = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT userid FROM KDDData.dbo.userprofile order by userid", con))
    {
        con.Open(); 
        using(SqlDataReader reader = result.ExecuteReader())
        {
           dt.Load(reader); 
           List<string> userids = new List<string>(dt.Rows.Count); 
           foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows) 
           { 
              userids.Add(item.ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim()); 
           }
        } 
        DataTable temp = new DataTable(); 
        foreach (string user in userids) 
        { 
            using(SqlCommand result1 = new SqlCommand( 
            "select itemid from KDDTrain.dbo.train where userid=" + user, con))
            {
                using(SqlDataReader reader1 = result1.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (!reader1.HasRows)   continue; 
                    temp.Load(reader1); 
                }
            } 
        } 
   }
```

Comment: the connections work fine its the ExecuteReader that's not working,besides,I was using the using() statements but had to remove them because I thought maybe they were causing problems

Comment: Looking again at your connection string, I am more sure than before that does not work with SqlServer. In that string is also missing the Initial Catalog/Database part. How can you connect to anything is a mistery to me. Please look at this [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Comment: you've got to be kidding me,i'm telling you it's working,its compiling,connecting and everything,I think you should check sql connections again.

Comment: Sorry to have upset you, but this is the first time that I see that connection syntax used against a SqlServer. I was curious and so I have tried against a database of mine with LinqPad and, sure, you were right, it works. Oh well glad that you have found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please insert this line

```
result1.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

befor this line in the second query

```
SqlDataReader reader1 = result1.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispose your reader after:

```
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    userids.Add(item.ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim()); 
}
```

...and also close the connection after temp.Load(reader1).  Also close the reader1.

Instead of all this... the clean way is to use USING for initializng the readers and connection. :)

Comment: Are you using OLEDB connection ? Take a look at this : http://www.dofactory.com/Connect/Connect.aspx

Comment: you are not paying much attention to the code,the SqlDataReaders are diffrent,it's the connection that is the same.by the way,I used some other connection,still didn't work.