# Filtering in timeouts in SQLExceptions

Tags: .net, sql, database, user-interface, sqlexception

I have an app that access various Oracle and SQL Server databases. I would the user to get a custom message if there is an exception because of a timeout.

Something like

> There was a timeout accessing the database, please run a search on
>   another test bench to ensure that the current test bench is running at
>   normal speed.

So how could I filter out these kinds of `SqlException`, caused by a slow-running DB Server?

Comment: possible duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241771/sql-timeout-exception

Comment: `caused by a slow-running DB Server`. Or lost tcp/ip packets, network conjestion, badly coded queries, etc, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: yogi, I'm not asking, like in the other question, for troubleshooting. I'm asking for a way to filter in SQLException caused by timeouts. Thanks for calling my question a duplicate a mere 3 minutes after I asked it.

Comment: Look at the properties of the exception when you get a timeout. Use those properties to distinguish between the timeout and non-timeout cases.